# 'second_file' has no attribute 'hello' -- Discord Python Bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I ran into the following problem :

First_File:

```
import discord
import second_file 
client = discord.Client()
[...]
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!hi"):
        await second_file.hello()
```

Second_File:

```
from first_file import client
from first_file import on_message
async def hello(client, on_message):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Hiii <3!")
```

And now I get the error message: `module 'second_file' has no attribute 'hello'`. 
Why won't it call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a cryptic error message compared to what's actually happening. You're attempting to import from both files at the same time and that causes issues. Whenever you import, the complete file will be interpreted, even though you're using `from file import thing`. To be more specific to your case, `await second_file.hello()` fails because `second_file` hasn't been fully imported yet when you get to it.

Here's what's being executed and why it fails (you can verify this from the stack trace that you get when you try to import the file in a python3 REPL):

1. `import second_file` in first_file, stops interpretation of first_file and triggers a complete interpretation of second_file.
2. `from first_file import client` stops interpretation of second_file and triggers a complete interpretation of first_file.
3. This time, `import second_file` is skipped (otherwise you'd get an infinite loop). Continue interpreting  first_file until...
4. `await second_file.hello()`: ignoring the syntax error where `hello()` accepts two arguments, notice the interpreter doesn't know about `hello()` yet. Obviously, this is a syntax error since you're using something you haven't defined yet!

To fix this, use the architecture you've already created. Just drop the two import statements at the start of second_file. I've also taken the liberty of adding the `message` argument it seems you forgot. Not sure why you even need the `on_message` function to be passed in, but to be fair I don't know your use case.

first_file

```
import discord
import second_file 
client = discord.Client()
[...]
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!hi"):
        await second_file.hello(client, on_message, message)
```

second_file

```
async def hello(client, on_message, message):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Hiii <3!")
```

Comment: `from first_file import client` doesn't "stop interpretation of second_file": `first_file` already exists in `sys.modules`, so it tries to use that.  The question should be "Why don't we get `ImportError: cannot import name 'client'` from that line?"

Comment: Perhaps I arrived at the right answer for the wrong reason. It seemed in my testing that the root cause was the import (as the fix I described in my answer that only removes the cyclic import does work). Try this out yourself with a MVCE (shouldn't be hard to make one), you get errors in interpretation of the file instead of an `ImportError`.

Comment: Thank you so much @PeterG !! This solved the problem! And you were right, I didn't need the "on_message" function :p! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @PeterG: My [(very) minimal VCE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Uv2SYpkaukxNQnEV) produces the `ImportError` I expected.  What code did you test?